# When Task Queue Stored Task Bytes quota is reset?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

For a couple of days now — maybe even weeks as I did not marked that in a calendar ;) — I have a high usage of Task Queue Stored Task Bytes quota and I wonder what to do, or how long to wait until it's freed.

My task queues are almost empty, they do stuff but not as much to justify high usage. I had period when I did a schema migration work that due to an error was a task-fork-bomb, and high usage was justified (see the bottom).

In [Quotas and Limits for Push Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push?hl=pl#Quotas_and_Limits_for_Push_Queues) it is written:

> Once a task has been executed or deleted, the storage used by that task is reclaimed. The reclaiming of storage quota for tasks happens at regular intervals, and this may not be reflected in the storage quota immediately after the task is deleted.

So how long are those regular intervals? After what time should I worry? After what time it is justified to file a [production issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue)?

> If a push task is created successfully, it will eventually be deleted (at most seven days after the task successfully executes). Once deleted, its name can be reused.

As mentioned earlier we had a task-fork-bomb but after it was spotted the queues where purged. Can it be the reason? Then how to purge data from a purged queues to reclaim the quota?

[Task names](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview?hl=pl#Task_Names) are supposed to lockout used names for 7 days but I'm sure the fork-bomb happened more that 7 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the storage will be reclaimed within a day.

If the storage quota hasn't been reclaimed after a few days, you should file a production issue, with your application name.